# Can't display validation errors with best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, rubygems

I am using the best_in_place gem with Rails 3.0.9. Seems like I have everything working. I followed the install instructions and I am able to click on an item, edit it and save all in the one spot with ajax.

However, when testing the validation functionality but putting in bogus data, the error message does not display.

I am not sure if this is supposed to be done magically through javascript, or if I am supposed to supply some sort of div tag or something where the error message can be displayed.

Checking into this in firebug, I am getting the correct json response. In my case I can see

> ["Debts has invalid length"]

but this does not get rendered anywhere.

Is there anything else I need to put in the view to render the validation error? It is supposed to be displayed via purr.js. Do I need to do anything besides put the javascript files in my public directory, initiate best_in_place in application.js and put

```
<p>
  <b>Debts:</b>
  <%= best_in_place @prospect, :debts, :type => :input %>
</p>
```

In the view?

Comment: Don't seem to be getting any answer on this. Wondering if it is a case of no one having the answer or more likely my question is not clear enough. Any suggestions on any other information I should provide are welcome.

Comment: What does your controller look like? Are you calling respond_with_bip in case the update fails?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem sounds just like mine: checking carefully at [Railscast #302](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast), I noticed that the error message was printing but in the bottom left of the page, hard to see and easy to miss.

The `purr CSS` code listed that page will format and display it more clearly on the web page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your should add the right controller action

```
def update
  ..
  respond_to do |format|   
    format.json { render json: @prospect } 
  end
end
```

or use the `respond_with_bip` helper instead. And do not forget to define the .purr CSS class, the "Best In Place" gem uses the jQuery Purr plugin to display error messages:

```
.purr {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FCC;
  border: solid 2px #C66;
  &:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take care. Add best_in_place.purr plugin instead of jquery.purr in application.js. It worked for me.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .
```